# How to use Google Chrome Browser for Testing in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, automation, robotframework, browser-automation

Recently Google Chrome introduced the Chrome browser for testing, specifically for automation. How to trigger the Chrome browser for testing in the robot framework?

For more info: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/
From Chrome version 114 onwards we will have to use Chrome browser for testing.
Can anyone help with this?

Also, the browser is closing automatically after the test, I haven't any teardown or close browser keywords.

Any way to solve this?

Comment: Try looking at [Robot Framework: The Ultimate Guide to Running Your Tests](https://www.appsierra.com/blog/robot-framework-to-run-automation-tests).

Comment: This change happened recently, the article is written in 2022. Not relevant 

Answer (score 0):

1. Download "Chrome for testing" and unpack it.
   E.g. to `C:\opt\chrome_for_testing\chrome-win64`
2. Matched chromedriver.exe should be available in system 'path'
3. Using in **RobotFramework** (command below is one line!):

```
open browser    browser=Chrome 
     options=binary_location=r"C:\\opt\\chrome_for_testing\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe"
```

4. using in **Python**

```py
    from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
        
    def start_chrome_for_testing_example():
        from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
        from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
        from selenium import webdriver
    
        opts = Options()
        opts.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        opts.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    
        opts.binary_location = r'C:\opt\chrome_for_testing\chrome-win64\chrome.exe'
        chromedriver = r"C:\opt\chrome_for_testing\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe"
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts, service=Service(chromedriver))
    
        selenium_library = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SeleniumLibrary")
        selenium_library._drivers.register(browser, 'chrome')
```

Checked in version:

- robotframework                   5.0.1
- robotframework-seleniumlibrary   6.1.0
- selenium                         4.9.1